# Match & Extract Multi-line Pattern In File

Tags: regex, bash, sed, match, multiline

I made a Bash script to download this page http://php.net/downloads.php and then search for the first occurrence of the latest PHP filename, version and MD5sum. Right now I have it working but broken up into two different sed commands. When I try to put the regexps into a single one it wont match. I believe it has to do with the newlines present.
How do I go about using one single sed pattern where I get all three matches in either an array (preferred) or seperated by spaces.

Btw, it does not have to be sed. I just want something where the system that the script will be run on will likely work, so no perl for instance.

```
wget -q http://php.net/downloads.php
FILE_INFO=$(sed -nr "s/.*(php-([0-9\.]+)\.tar\.bz2).*/\1 \2/p;T;q" downloads.php)
MD5SUM=$(sed -nr "s/.*md5: ([0-9a-f]{32}).*/\1/p;T;q" downloads.php)

echo $FILE_INFO
echo $MD5SUM
```

These are the two lines from the file in question and it needs to extract the info from:

```
  <a href="/get/php-5.4.5.tar.bz2/from/a/mirror">PHP 5.4.5 (tar.bz2)</a> [10,754Kb] -  19 July 2012<br />
  <span class="md5sum">md5: ffcc7f4dcf2b79d667fe0c110e6cb724</span>
```

Comment: Are they always in the same order? Then quit only after printing the second. Look up `T` and `t` in your `sed` man page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '\|<a href="/get/php|!d;N;s/.*\(php-\([0-9\.]\+\)\.tar\.bz2\).*md5: \([0-9a-f]\{32\}\).*/\1 \2 \3/;q' file
```

Comment: Accepting you answer since it is more what I was wanting, and it returns only the first occurances as specified in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -nr 's/.*(php-([0-9\.]+)\.tar\.bz2).*/\1 \2/p;s/.*md5: ([0-9a-f]{32}).*/\1/p;T;' downloads.php
```

Comment: Works great in matching all occurances of pattern :). How do I make it so it just matchs the first occurance and returns just 3 strings the filename, version and md5? Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: It does work, but it matched ALL occurances of the pattern which was not what the original question had asked for. Stephane's solution only matched the first occurance of each pattern and thus provided an accurate solution to my question. I wish I could split the accept, if there is a way to please tell me and I will. New to this site.